# c# virtual methods in class that implements interface

Tags: c#, polymorphism, virtual

Lets say I have the following class:

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    [TypeLibType((short)2)]
    [ClassInterface((short)0)]
    [ComImport]
    public class myClass : myInterface
    {
        public virtual void myMethod();
    }
}
```

and lets say I have the following interface which that class implements

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    [Guid("2105896C-2B38-4031-BD0B-7A9C4A39FB93")]
    [TypeLibType((short)4160)]
    [ComImport]
    public interface myInterface
    {
        void myMethod();
    }
}
```

Now, when I compile this the virtual method in the first class comes back with the following error:

```
'myNamespace.myClass.myMethod()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
```

This method should compile just fine because it is marked as virtual, but for some reason it still will not compile and I'm kind of at a loss as to why because if I alternatively define a body on MyMethod in MyClass then I get the following error instead:

```
Since 'myClass.myMethod' has the ComImport attribute, 'myNamespace.myClass.myMethod' must be extern or abstract
```

I'm using .Net 3.5 for this setup, but it still doesn't work in .Net 4.0 either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are confusing `virtual` with `abstract`.  Virtual methods require an implemenation, but *may* be overridden.

Abstract methods on the other hand can be declared as you have it without an implementation.  Subclasses then bear the responsibility of providing the implementation, and if they don't they are greeted with a compiler error.

Comment: yea I was originally confused about that, however it appears that my issue is with the [ComImport] attribute on myClass.  I cannot define a method body in that class when the class has the ComImport attribute, but it won't let the class compile with a body defined unless you pass it 'extern' instead of 'virtual'...but I don't think  that will work for what I need...

Comment: @Robert - Is there a reason you are applying `ComImport` manually?

Comment: because if you don't specify it then when you access the method from the client you run into a security exception of

"ECall methods must be packaged into a system module."

not sure how to get around that

Comment: @Robert, there appears to be a dearth of information online about `[ComImport]` but everything about how you are using it suggests to me that you should declare it `extern`.  Have you tried that?  Does it not work?

Comment: yea I tried that, and that is the correct answer to the situation, but it didn't work in my situation as I was looking at the wrong piece of my puzzle.  I was working on replacing a driver for a device which was no longer supported by our vendor to get it to run on 64 bit but after a little more digging I realized was looking at too high of a level anyways, as the problem was in the actual driver itself being incompatible.  So this question is no longer needed.  I will mark this answer as the right choice though as it was the answer to my original issue.  Thanks for your help though guys!